# React - How to change className by index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-props

I created a simple logic: when you click on a certain block, the `classname` changes, but the problem is that when you click on a certain block, the `classname` changes and the rest of the blocks looks like this

[image]

I need to change only the name of the class that I clicked, I think I need to use the index, but I don't quite understand how to reolize it

```
export default function SelectGradientTheme(props) {
    const resultsRender = [];
    const [borderColor, setBorderColor] = useState(false);

    const setBorder = () => {
        setBorderColor(!borderColor)
    }

    const borderColorClassName = borderColor ? "selectBorder" : null;

    for (var i = 0; i < GradientThemes.length; i += 3) {
        resultsRender.push(
            <div className={"SelectThemePictures_Separator"}>
                {
                    GradientThemes.slice(i, i + 3).map((col, index) => {
                        return (
                            <div key={index} className={borderColorClassName} onClick={() => props.SideBarPageContent(col)|| setBorder()}>
                            </div>
                        );
                    })
                }
            </div>
        )
    }


    return (
        <div className="SelectThemeWrapper">
            {resultsRender}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remember the selected index

Please reference the following code:

```
export default function SelectGradientTheme(props) {
    const resultsRender = [];
    const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(false);

    const setBorder = (index) => {
        setSelectedIndex(index);
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < GradientThemes.length; i += 3) {
        resultsRender.push(
            <div className={"SelectThemePictures_Separator"}>
                {
                    GradientThemes.slice(i, i + 3).map((col, index) => {
                        return (
                            <div key={index}
                                className={index === selectedIndex ? 'selectBorder' : null}
                                onClick={() => props.SideBarPageContent(col)|| setBorder(index)}>
                            </div>
                        );
                    })
                }
            </div>
        )
    }


    return (
        <div className="SelectThemeWrapper">
            {resultsRender}
        </div>
    );
};
```