# React - When checked, the old condition is retained

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I had an incomprehensible problem just a few days ago, I asked a question related to getting an index of values [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66447998/react-how-to-change-classname-by-index/66448095#66448095) I got a reliable answer and everything worked well for me after I slightly changed my existing code.

When I click on a certain block, it is highlighted in blue (this is how it should be), but the problem is that after clicking on another block, the old color from the block does not disappear, it looks like this

[image]

As you can see, after clicking on a new block from the old color does not disappear, how to solve this problem?

**SelectColorsTheme.js**

```
export default function SelectColorsTheme(props) {
    const rows = SideBarColors.map(function (col, index) {
        
        return <SelectThemeContent {...props} col={col} key={index} index={index}/>
    }).reduce(// code) {
        // code
    });
    return <div className="container">{rows}</div>;
};
```

**SelectThemeContent.jsx**

```
export default function SelectThemeContent(props) {

    const { col, index } = props;

    const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(false);

    const setBorder = (index) => {
        setSelectedIndex(index);
    };

    const selectBorder = classNames({
        'builtin_theme_preview': true,
        'selectBorder': index === selectedIndex ? 'selectBorder' : null
    });

    return (
        <div className={selectBorder} key={index} onClick={() => props.SideBarPageContent(col) || setBorder(index)}>
// code
</div>
```

Comment: Can there be atmost one selection only ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want only one item being selected, you need to lift state up from **SelectThemeContent** to **SelectColorsTheme**. Currently each child has its own state that knows nothing about the siblings.

So this code must be in **SelectColorsTheme** -

```
const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(false);

const setBorder = (index) => {
    setSelectedIndex(index);
};
```

Then pass **setBorder** function in props from **SelectColorsTheme** down to **SelectThemeContent**:

```
return <SelectThemeContent {...props} col={col} key={index} index={index} setBorder={setBorder}/>
```

And replace the handler in **SelectThemeContent**:

```
onClick={() => props.SideBarPageContent(col) || props.setBorder(index)}
```